# Login Session Issue in Codeigniter

Tags: php, html, codeigniter, web, codeigniter-3

I create login form with multi level function, the code for multi level is working but I have a problem on session, when I login to my account as an admin and direct to admin dashboard but I still can use back page which directly to login page again, so what have I missed?

my login controller:

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') or exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Login extends CI_Controller
{
    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('login_model');
        $this->load->library('session');
        $this->load->helper('url');
        // $this->load->library('form_validation');
    }

    function index()
    {

            $datatitle['title'] = 'Login LPPM UTY';
            $this->load->view('auth/tamplate/auth_header', $datatitle);
            $this->load->view('auth/login_v');
            $this->load->view('auth/tamplate/auth_footer');

    }

    function auth()
    {
        $username = htmlspecialchars($this->input->post('username', TRUE), ENT_QUOTES);
        $password = htmlspecialchars($this->input->post('password', TRUE), ENT_QUOTES);
        $cek_admin = $this->login_model->auth_admin($username,$password);

        if ($cek_admin->num_rows() > 0) { //jika login sebagai admin
            $data = $cek_admin->row_array();
            $this->session->set_userdata('masuk', TRUE);
            if ($data['level'] == '1') 
            { //Akses admin

                $this->session->set_userdata('akses', '1');
                $this->session->set_userdata('user', $data['username']);
                $this->session->set_userdata('name', $data['name']);
                redirect('admin');
            } else { // jika username dan password tidak ditemukan atau salah
                $url = base_url();
                echo $this->session->set_flashdata('notif', '<div class="alert 
                    alert-danger" role="alert">Username Atau Password Salah
                    </div>');
                redirect($url);
            }
        } else { //jika login sebagai dosen
            $cek_dosen = $this->login_model->auth_dosen($username, $password);
            if ($cek_dosen->num_rows() > 0) {
                $data = $cek_dosen->row_array();
                $this->session->set_userdata('masuk', TRUE);
                ($data['level'] == '2');
                $this->session->set_userdata('akses', '2');
                $this->session->set_userdata('user', $data['username']);
                $this->session->set_userdata('name', $data['name']);
                redirect('dosen');
            } else {  // jika username dan password tidak ditemukan atau salah
                $url = base_url();
                echo $this->session->set_flashdata('notif', '<div class="alert 
                    alert-danger" role="alert">Username Atau Password Salah
                    </div>');
                redirect($url);
            }
        }
    }

      function logout(){
          $this->session->sess_destroy();
          redirect('login');
      }
}
```

Model login_model:

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') or exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Login_model extends CI_Model
{
    function auth_admin($username, $password)
    {
        $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM admin_login WHERE username='$username' AND password=md5('$password') LIMIT 1");
        return $query;
    }

    //cek username dan password pengajar
    function auth_dosen($username, $password)
    {
        $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM dosen_login WHERE username='$username' AND password=md5('$password') LIMIT 1");
        return $query;
    }

}
```

Admin Controller:

```
<?php

class Admin extends CI_Controller
{
    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->library('session');
        $this->load->model('m_admin');
        if ($this->session->userdata('masuk') != TRUE) {
            $this->load->helper('url');
            redirect('login');
        }
    }
    function index()
    {
        if($this->session->userdata('akses') =='1'){     

            $datatitle['title'] = 'Beranda Admin';
            $this->load->view("dashboard/admin/header_admin_v", $datatitle);        
            $this->load->view("dashboard/admin/home_admin_v");  
            $this->load->view("dashboard/admin/footer_admin_v");
        } else {
            echo "Access Denied";
        }
    }
    public function show_dosen($nidn){
        if($this->session->userdata('akses') == '1'){
            $nidn = array('nidn' => $nidn);
            $data['dosen'] = $this->m_admin->edit_tampil($nidn,'data_dosen')->result();
            $info = $this->m_admin->edit_tampil($nidn,'data_dosen')->result();
            $user = $this->m_admin->edit_tampil($nidn,'dosen_login')->result();
            $dataa = array(
                'info' => $info,
                'user' => $user
            );
            $this->load->view('dosen/dosen_data',$dataa);              
        }
        else{            
            echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("Sesi habis! Login Lagi!")</script>'; 
            $this->load->view('login');
        }         
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you asking why you come to the login page when you use the back button after a successful login? What else  would you expect happening and why?

Comment: **Warning!** Don't use md5 for password hashing! [The manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.md5.php) even states: _"Warning - It is not recommended to use this function to secure passwords, due to the fast nature of this hashing algorithm"_. You should use PHP's [password_hash()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) to create a secure hash. Then you can use [password_verify()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) to verify a password against a hash.

Comment: Also, why are you using `htmlspecialchars()` on the posted data? I don't see you outputting those values anywhere?

Comment: You are also open for [SQL injection](https://owasp.org/www-community/attacks/SQL_Injection) attacks. Read the [documentation](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/queries.html#query-bindings) about how you safely bind params to your queries. Specially since you're not currently escaping the data from SQL injections at all.

Comment: @Magnus yes iam asking why my back page still working after succesful login, when i hit back my web back to login form again, i expect after login succesful session no allowed my back page go to login form again

Comment: If you want that behavior, you need to build it. The server/browser doesn't know how you want them to behave unless you tell them. In the method that loads the login page, you need to check if the user is logged in and if they are, redirect them to the dashboard and if they aren't, show the login view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check your session in construct

```
function __construct ()
    {
        parent ::__construct ();

        if ($this -> session -> userdata ( "akses" ) == 1) {
            redirect ( "admin/dashboard" , "refresh" );
        }
        if ($this -> session -> userdata ( "akses" ) == 2) {
            redirect ( "user/dashboard" , "refresh" );
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Generate a session to know if the admin is logged in--

```
$this->session->set_userdata('is_admin_login', 1)
```

Check if the session is generated on your login url(controller)--

```
function index(){
    if ($this->session->userdata('is_admin_login')) {
        redirect('admin/home');  // redirect to desired location
    }

    $datatitle['title'] = 'Login LPPM UTY';
    $this->load->view('auth/tamplate/auth_header', $datatitle);
    $this->load->view('auth/login_v');
    $this->load->view('auth/tamplate/auth_footer');
}
```